# What does a note with no head mean?

Tags: guitar, notation

There's a piece of notation in a guitar book I'm using that I can't find any information about. The note appears without a head:

[image: The note appears without a head].

I would guess that it symbolizes "play the previous note again" but slash notation is used earlier in the same exercise:

[image: earlier in the same exercise]

Thanks!

Comment: It's certainly indicative of laziness on the part of the typesetter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first example with no note heads I would interpret as, apply the previous voicing to the written rhythm till you reach a new written note.

Slashes however in jazz and pop music charts imply flexibility choosing the notes you play as long as the chords and rhythms are correct.

Does the accompanying CD provide recordings of the exercises you can listen to for reference?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've had the book for a long time and don't have the CD anymore. Your response makes a lot of sense to me though, thanks!!

Comment: "Stems alone may indicate repeated chords." (Elaine Gould, *Behind Bars*, p. 231)